# Firefox display:table-cell bug, or how does table-cell work?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-tables

I have this code:

```
<style>
    .main-table {width: 80%;}
    .box, .placeholder-box {display:table-cell; width: 26.4%;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="main-table">
    <tr>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Venue</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <h1>Time</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <h1>Registry & Gifts</h1>
        </div>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Dress</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="placeholder-box">
            [Floral placeholder thing]
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Firefox treats the divs as all appearing in the dom before the table, so there is no tabular layout of my divs. This seems like it is ignoring the `display:table-cell`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is FF broken? Is there a better way to lay things out in a grid than using a table?

Comment: What is it supposed to look like? A quick image (or ASCII art) would make it very clear.

Comment: What I want is a 3 x 2 table; what I'm getting is all of the divs laid out one after the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to xhtml.com](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/tr/), a `tr` has to contain at least one `th` or `td`. Firefox probably *only* allows `th` or `td`, and is "fixing" your mistake for you.

Also, couldn't you layout your HTML like this?:

```
.main-table {width: 80%;}
.box, .placeholder-box {display:table-cell; width: 26.4%;}

<div class="main-table">
    <div>
        <div class="box">...</div>
        <div class="box">...</div>
        <div class="box">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's more inline with the purpose of `display:table-cell`.

Comment: @thirtydot Uh oh. Cross-commenting. I don't know if you're disagreeing or clarifying.

Comment: I was *agreeing* and clarifying. I edited in the 'So Firefox is indeed trying to "fix it"' part to try to make my intention clearer.

Comment: Yes, sort of - if I assign my cells a fixed width (e.g. 300px), I get a tabular layout, BUT if I use a relative width (e.g. 33%), FF does not give them all the same width, so the tabular effect is broken.

Comment: FWIW, this "fixing" behaviour is known in the HTML5 parsing algorithm as "Foster Parenting". You can find the details here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tokenization.html#foster-parenting

Comment: This would probably have worked as XHTML, which does no fixing of any sort.